# How do I properly install django registration on localhost?

Tags: python, django

I have a directory for a django project on my localhost

/MyDjangoList/

In this folder I have a django application called PK

I downloaded django-registration and unzipped the folder into the /MyDjangoList/

I went into terminal and went to the django-registration folder and ran

python setup.py install.

It did a bunch of things then spit out the following:

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration': Permission denied

The Install file says I can just put it into the same folder as my project, so do I even need to install this? If so, how do I properly install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install it to a system folder, I'd recommend:

```
sudo pip install django-registration
```

you may need to:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

beforehand (assuming ubu/debian).

If you'd like to put it alongside in a folder instead, unzip it, and use it just as if it was another Django app.  That means take a look and see that everything is in the standard places, e.g:

```
.../<project>/<app>/{*.py|models|templates|etc..}
```

Comment: so put it into the app folder and not into the project folder? i.e. put it into /project/app/registration instead of /project/registration?

Comment: Nope, ./project/registration, I used "app" as a generic app name.  Maybe I can clarify the text a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need more permission? As in you need to do:  `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: does that link the registration app to the pk app?

Comment: Install it on the system `sudo python setup.py install` and then you'll add it to your PK project in the `settings.py` file under `INSTALLED_APPS` as probably `django-registration`

Answer (score 1):

i'd also add that there is a set of default templates somewhere that make the usage of registration vastly easier. think they were on ubernostrums google code last time i needed them.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you make a build before installing the django registration. From terminal navigate to the django-registration directory and build by using the command

```
python setup.py build
```

In that way it will check for all dependencies and suggest if any problem occurs. After that install it by using command

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

As simple as that.